# How to reduce the margins in KOMA-Script

Tags: margins, koma-script

I am making a report using LaTeX.  It is looking fine but there is a really large space taken up by the margins. Here is the main tex file:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%    homebrew commands -- to save typing
\newcommand\msp{\textup{\normalsize MSP430 Launchpad }}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\def\onequarter{\frac{1}{4}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% New colors

\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{255,127,0}

\begin{document}
\input{./title.tex}
\input{./cert.tex}
\input{./ack.tex}

\tableofcontents
\input{./intro.tex}
\input{./learn.tex}
\input{./comp_list.tex}
\input{./comp_desc.tex}
\input{./block.tex}
\input{./ckt_dia.tex}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Bibliography}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

How may I reduce the margin to maybe half of what it is right now?

Comment: These "larger margins" are good typography. Please read the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.html) for koma-script.

Answer (score 24):

The easiest way is perhaps to use the `DIV=<value>` option for the document class, see table 2.1 in section 2.6 *Options and Macros to Influence the Page Layout* in the (English version of) the KOMA-script manual (dated 2013-12-19). You can choose integers from 6 to 16, where larger numbers give a larger type area, i.e. smaller margins.

For example

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,DIV=14]{scrreprt}
```

Browsing the manual, I also see that you can set the type area with

```
\areaset[BCOR]{Width}{Height}
```

where `BCOR` is binding correction. Read chapter 2 *Construction of the page layout with typearea* of KOMA script's manual for more information.

Comment: `Options and Macros to Influence the Page Layout` can now be found in section 2.6. The German title is `Einstellung des Satzspiegels und der Seitenaufteilung`.

Comment: @ComFreek Thanks, I edited my answer slightly.

Comment: You can choose a large number like DIV=50 as well! After that, I think it's not useful anymore...

Answer (score 13):

You can use the geometry package to easily change the margins:

```
\usepackage[top=tlength, bottom=blength, left=llength, right=rlength]{geometry}
```

Or

```
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
```

EDIT: For KOMA-Script, you should use the typearea package that is part of the bundle to change the page layout, not the geometry package. See Chapter 2 of the [KOMA-Script Documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf)

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't - the page layout done by koma-script is good typography.

Comment: The link is broken for me.

Comment: I've updated the link.

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb fixed link