# How can I reduce the left margin in the documentclass hitec?

Tags: packages, margins, document-classes, geometry

I am quite aware of the package `geometry`, but it does not seem to play nice with the hitec document class. I have looked at related questions [How to reduce the margins in KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32028/how-to-reduce-the-margins) and [How can I change the margins in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94795/how-can-i-change-the-margins-in-latex?rq=1)

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{hitec}
%\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\author{Merlin $merlin@merlin.com$}
\title{Arbitrary Title}

\maketitle

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the line `\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}`, a lot of text flies off the left side of the page. Moreover, the two horizontal lines on the top and bottom of the title do not move.

I suspect that the document class is doing something unusual with the usage of margins, but I wonder if there is a systematic way to just shift everything to the left by 1 cm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line width is controlled via

```
\settextfraction
```

The default is `\settextfraction{0.8}`; by issuing `\settextfraction{1}` in the preamble, the text left margin will be flush with the section titles.

The left margin (measured from the left edge of the paper to the left edge of the section titles) is equal to the right margin and should be one inch. If you want to change it you have to modify the definition of `\settextfraction` (or act manually on the parameters after `\begin{document}`, which is not recommended).